# Why did Kaguya cry and run away?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-tale-of-the-princess-kaguya

Somewhere near the end of the Tale of Princess Kaguya, Kaguya is returning home in a carriage and she spots Sutemaru. He has robbed someone and is running with some vegetables in his hands. They see each other, she smiles, he trips.

Then Kaguya starts crying and hides in the wagon. Sutemaru is caught and beaten up for being a thief. Kaguya hears him crying and yelling, but ignores him and leaves.

What just happened? Why would she behave this poorly?

Comment: Unfortunately, this scene is not explained or even mentioned in the Behind the Scenes documentary.